# Get CMake project version added by add_subdirectory

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake project that depends on Google Test library.
I've added Google Test using `ExternalProject_Add` and `add_subdirectory` as described here (https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest section `Incorporating Into An Existing CMake Project`).

Now, after command `add_subdirectory` I want to check version of included project `gtest` and `gmock`, however `gtest_VERSION` and `gmock_VERSION` variables is undefined. Is it possible to get project version added by `add_subdirectory`?

Comment: Well, how can I "grep" `CMakeLists.txt` internals? Write some script parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable [<PROJECT-NAME>_VERSION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/PROJECT-NAME_VERSION.html) has a **local scope**. Thus a version variable, defined by a subproject, is not visible by a main project.

Assuming a subproject's `CMakeLists.txt` performs `project()` call like

```
project(<project-name> VERSION <version-string> ...)
```

version string can be easily extracted with regular expressions:

```
# subproject_version(<subproject-name> <result-variable>)
#
# Extract version of a sub-project, which was previously included with add_subdirectory().
function(subproject_version subproject_name VERSION_VAR)
    # Read CMakeLists.txt for subproject and extract project() call(s) from it.
    file(STRINGS "${${subproject_name}_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt" project_calls REGEX "[ \t]*project\\(")
    # For every project() call try to extract its VERSION option
    foreach(project_call ${project_calls})
        string(REGEX MATCH "VERSION[ ]+([^ )]+)" version_param "${project_call}")
        if(version_param)
            set(version_value "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
    if(version_value)
        set(${VERSION_VAR} "${version_value}" PARENT_SCOPE)
    else()
        message("WARNING: Cannot extract version for subproject '${subproject_name}'")
    endif()

endfunction(subproject_version)

# The function's usage:    
subproject_version(gtest gtest_version)
message("VERSION for gtest: ${gtest_version}")
```

---

Implementation above uses variable [<PROJECT-NAME>_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/PROJECT-NAME_SOURCE_DIR.html), which contains source directory of the subproject. Unlike to `<PROJECT-NAME>_VERSION` variable, variable with source directory has *global visibility* (it is *CACHED*, actually), thus it can be used outside of the subproject.

Comment: It's worth noting that this won't work if the sub-project splits its call to `project()` among multiple lines. While this is certainly possible to handle with more common regex engines, I wasn't able to come up with an expression that worked with CMake's more limited one. Notably, due to its lack of lazy quantifiers and single-line mode.

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't have direct access to sub-directories local variables, I wanted to add my variants of making the `gtest_VERSION` variable `CACHED` and therefore globally accessible:

1. [`CMAKE_PROJECT_<PROJECT-NAME>_INCLUDE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PROJECT_PROJECT-NAME_INCLUDE.html)

   > A CMake language file or module to be included by the [`project()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html#command:project) command. This is intended for injecting custom code into project builds without modifying their source.

   ```perl
   file(
       WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/SetProjectVersion.cmake"
       [=[
           set(${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION "${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
       ]=]
   )
   set(
       CMAKE_PROJECT_gtest_INCLUDE
       "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/SetProjectVersion.cmake"
   )
   ```
2. Overwrite the [`project()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) command

   ```perl
   cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)    

   macro(project)
       _project(${ARGN})
       set(${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION "${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
   endmacro()
   ```